# TypeError: value.forEach is not a function when calling a function

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapps

I am using Truffle to deploy a contract on Ganache and retrieve the contract in an express app.
While I can get the contract instance and it can console.log a list of function object, the function cannot be called in the code.

Here is my contract:

```
contract Vote{
    uint dem = 0;
    uint pub = 0;

    constructor() public {
        dem = 0;
        pub = 0;
    }

    function vote(uint v) public {
        if(v == 1){
            pub += 1;
        } else {
            dem += 1;
        }
    }

    function getWinner() public view returns (uint) {
        if(dem > pub){
            return dem;
        } else {
            return 0 - pub;
        }
    }
}
```

Code call the function:

```
var voteAbi = [{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getWinner","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"v","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
var voteContract = web3.eth.contract(voteAbi);
var voteInstance = voteContract.at("0x0711217536458a37580e669de781554ce33236c24711d351d446a437e16ae058");
voteInstance.vote.call(1)
voteInstance.vote(1)
voteInstance.vote.sendTransaction(1,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0]})
```

All the three lines call the function vote result in the Foreach problem.
I am new to web3 and blockchain! Any ideas on what could go wrong here?

Comment: What is the version of your web3?

Comment: You need to put those lines in an `async` function, and add `await` in some of them (the last 3 for sure, the one before them if your web3.js version is 1 or higher).

Comment: in addition to what @goodvibration said. you need to change `web3.eth.contract(voteAbi)` to `web3.eth.Contract(voteAbi)` in web3 version 1 or higher. (notice that Contract has a capital C )

Comment: @Masoudjt: You're wrong about the `await`. This is just the creation of a local `web3.eth.Contract` object. There is no interaction with the remote node here, hence no need to asynchronously await for it to complete.

Comment: @goodvibration yes. thanks. edited.

Answer (score 1):

your calling data before it's inserted in blockchain. Use async funtion in web3JS like this:

```
var voteAbi = [{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getWinner","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"v","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
var voteContract = web3.eth.contract(voteAbi);
var voteInstance = voteContract.at("0x0711217536458a37580e669de781554ce33236c24711d351d446a437e16ae058");


async function votingBro(){
   await voteInstance.vote.call(1)
   await voteInstance.vote(1)
   await voteInstance.vote.sendTransaction(1,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0]})
}

votingBro()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem caused by Truffle. When I move to remix and deploy the contract in my ganache-cli, it works.

Comment: Don’t unlock accounts, better to sign the transactions with the private key.